# chown has no effect even after it claims it changed owner

Tags: 12.04, chown

The user 'user' exists on the server. The group 'homeusers' exist on the server.

This is what is happenening:

```
user@localhost / $ ssh user@server
user@server:~$ lsb_release -a
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
user@server:~$ cd /mount/somedir/
user@server:/mount/somedir$ ls -al
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Nov 24 20:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov 30 10:11 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Dec  2 02:11 somechild
user@server:/mount/somedir$ sudo chown -v user:homeusers somechild
changed ownership of `somechild' from root:root to user:homeusers
user@server:/mount/somedir$ ls -al
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Nov 24 20:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov 30 10:11 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Dec  2 02:11 somechild
```

Comment: Ran df -Th and it shows as a fuseblk mount, meaning it's a NFTS mount. I think that has something to do with it.

Comment: `chown` will have no effect on mounted disks/partitions. If you need to mount a partition with specific owner/group privileges, you need to specify that in the `mount` command or through your `fstab` entry.

Comment: +douggro, even if the mount isn't NTFS? If I mounted ext4, isn't it okay to chown the files when mounted? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. NTFS is the culprit. Ubuntu will mount the NTFS partition as root, but with all permissions as 777 for files and 755 for directories.

As mentioned, you should be able to specify the owner with the mount command:

```
sudo mount -o uid=`id -u user` /dev/sdX /mount/somedir
```

Comment: Updating fstab to include the gid and uid resolved the issue. I'll need to move to an ext format though since I need more granular control. Thanks

Comment: Note this commonly affects vagrant shared folders on Windows using VirtualBox. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169154/cannot-change-permissions-of-folders-within-vagrant-home-folder